# Magento Commerce connection from webshop

Tags: magento-connect

netstat tells me there is connection from/to (?) magentocommerce, for instance:

```
tcp        0      0 server_ip:49737       server_ip:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 server_ip:39654       66.211.190.109:80       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 server_ip:39655       66.211.190.109:80       TIME_WAIT   -
```

I can reproduce these logs (the number of lines from 66.211.190.109 varies a lot) when logging from backend on the 'magento connect' interface. Mainly by clicking 'check for updates'.

1. Are these logs only produced by user interaction or is there any automatic connection?
2. If that's auto-connections, can we set somewhere a time window for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Magento installation connects to magentocommerce.com to get the Admin Notifications you see under the menubar in the Admin section of the shop.

The cron settings for this connection are under `System > Configuration > System > Notifications`

Comment: ok, that's one point. What about the other? (how to setup a time window for these connections)

Comment: Ah right, updated

Comment: Still have frequent connection, despite the configuration set to 24h (and hit the save button), is there a daemon to restart, database manipulation or something else?

Comment: nope, you could do a grep over the whole codebase on the url `grep -Ri 'magentocommerce.com' .` and see what comes out of that